# Best approch for side scrolling game , cocos2d box2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scroll, box2d, parallax

I am trying to develop a game like ninja jump in ios with cocos2d + box2d with endless scrolling ! (no need of parallax scrolling)
What is the best practice for endless scrolling

1 : moving the layer (Ie changing the layer position)
2 : moving the Camara
3 : using parallax scrolling with single layer (ie using only one parallax layer with same speed)

Or any other better approch
?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look to this tutorial: [How to Make a Game Like Jetpack Joyride using LevelHelper and SpriteHelper](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6929/how-to-make-a-game-like-jetpack-joyride-using-levelhelper-spritehelper-part-1).

It explains you how to make an endless scrolling game like (Jetpack Joyride) using Cocos2D and Box2D.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider Parallax scrolling approach ..!

Answer (score 1):

You can use parallax scrolling for the background layer and reset the game objects once they go out of the screen.